# NullPointerException on AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar, android-asynctask

So I'm trying to write an `AsyncTask`, other `UI` functions seem to work `onPostExecute`, such as inflating and adding layouts/views but when I try to change visibility of a progress bar, I get a Null Pointer exception.

I'm not using `onPostExecute` directly, but rather using an addObserver / callback combination, which the function contains this:

```
ProgressBar featuredLoading = (ProgressBar)featuredLayout.findViewById(R.id.featuredLoading);
featuredLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Any ideas?

Edit: seems to be un-releated to the async task, moving it outside to before the asynctask is even executed (onCreateView) still crashes the program... How can I be allowed to change a LinearLayout properties fine but not a ProgressBar?

Comment: Idea: `findViewById` returns `null`. No idea why, though, not enough data for that.

Comment: your progress bar isn't currently on the featuredLayout. So findViewById() is returning null. Post more code if you want more help fixing

Comment: Thanks - I think that's it. I moved stuff around, and it is no longer inside featuredLoading but one level up.